# Spark SQL With Case and Sum

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have one hive table in which I have columns(id, dept, salary) I am applying some transformation on that table using spark SQL.

i.e. if the department is HR then salary=salary+100, if the department is IT then salary=salary+0 and based on department taking the sum of salaries. PFB

**Input Data**

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id |   dept    | salary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | HR        |    100 |
|  2 | operation |    200 |
|  3 | tech      |    300 |
|  4 | IT        |    400 |
|  1 | HR        |    500 |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id |   dept    | salary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | HR        |    800 |
|  2 | operation |    300 |
|  3 | tech      |    300 |
|  4 | IT        |    400 |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

I have written below code but it's not working in spark sql.

```
spark.sql("select CASE WHEN dept = 'HR' THEN 'sum(salary+100)',when  dept = 'IT' THEN 'sum(salary+0)' ELSE 'salary' END AS salary from emp group by dept").show
```

but getting mismatched input: issue. Please help how should I Implement this.

Comment: Does `salary+0` makes any sense to you?

Comment: The output for `operation` is wrong

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz  No,I need to Increment salary based on departments.(salary+0) just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Dept, sum(salary + case Dept when 'HR' then 100 when 'IT' then 0 else 0 end)
From emp
Group by Dept
```

Or

```
Select Dept, sum(salary) + sum(case Dept when 'HR' then 100 when 'IT' then 0 else 0 end)
From emp
Group by Dept
```

Answer (score 1):

expected output: spark sql query is

```
spark.sql("Select id,dept, sum(salary) + sum(case dept when 'HR' then 100 when 'IT' then 0 when 'operation' then 100 else 0 end) as salary  From employee1 group by id,dept order by id asc").show()
```

[image: output]

I hope this helps.